# Object elements auto height doesn't work

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to add a flash game to an html web page.

```css
.gameplace{
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: dashed #c4b470 1px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
.gameplace object{
    width: 853px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='main-filler'>
<div class='main-info'>  
    <div class='gameplace'>
        <object data='test.swf'></object>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to automatically count the height of the swf file but nothing appears. Instead if I put a specific height the swf file will run normally, the problem is that I want to put the real height of the swf file automatically by the browser ..

Please how can I do this and sorry for the bad language :)

Comment: Did you try to specify the `width` only (and omit the `height` completely)?

Comment: yes .. also doesn't works ..

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the image element with an swf object should work fine.

```js
$("#getHeight1").click(function() {
  alert($("#swfobject1").height());
});

$("#getHeight2").click(function() {
  alert($("#swfobject2").height());
});
```

```css
  .gameplace {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: dashed #c4b470 1px;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
  }
  .gameplace img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='main-filler'>
  <div class='main-info' style='width: 200px;'>
    <div class='gameplace'>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" id="swfobject1"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class='main-filler'>
  <div class='main-info'>
    <div class='gameplace'>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200" id="swfobject2"/>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p>
  <button id="getHeight1">Get height of object 1</button>
  <button id="getHeight2">Get height of object 2</button>
</p>
```